# String as send buffer with multiprocessing access

Tags: python, sockets, serial-port, multiprocessing

In Python how do I fill a buffer with lines of data (strings) and consume it with a second process? There are ample of examples here adding and reading lines from a string, but I need to remove the consumed line from the string for the string to work as a buffer.

Example: read sporadic data from a serial port and send it via TCP/IP to a server. Line-by-line within one loop and no buffering = no problem, but in case the destination is unreachable the data should be stored in the buffer and then sent once connection is available.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process

ip = "someURL"
port = 12345
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 57600, timeout=0)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def serial_reader():
    while True:
        for line in ser.read():
            try:
                response = ser.readlines(None)
                response = str(response)
                message = response[7:]
            except:
                print datetime.datetime.now(), " No data from serial connection."
##

def data_sender():
    s.connect((ip, port))
    while True:
        for line in queue():
            try:
                s.send(message)
            except:
                try:
                    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    s.connect((ip, port))
                    continue
                except:
                    s.close()
##

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=serial_reader).start()
    Process(target=data_sender).start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to use a queue:

`from multiprocessing import Queue`

specifically use `queue.put()` to put a string on the queue, `queue.get()` to retrieve it, and `queue.task_done()` to indicate that the task is complete.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue

if you need a bigger gun take a look at RabbitMQ and python libraries that implement the AMPQ protocol such as `rabbitpy`. This is the defacto standard for inter process/inter service communication and has a lot of usefyl stuff already baked in, such as persisting messages in case the processes shut down, load balancing tasks across multiple processes, etc.